# Cold start recommender system implementation

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

I have to implement a recommender system model.
The data I have been provided is unique ID and ICD codes of the patients.
How am I supposed to build the system when every new case has a unique id and there seems to be no relationship between the data?

Answer (score 0):

## Two ways:

### 1. regard it as a unk id and train your model every day .

### 2. online learning for every new id .

Comment: which algorithm will you recommend? I know that for every new unique id there is not going to be any new information related to the learned ICD codes. 

So when I have trained the model for unique ids along with their ICD codes. and while testing I have to provide a unique ID and get relevant ICDs without any information of the patient?

Comment: What you should do is that preprocess the id feature in a correct way , not select a correct model . In fact , you can use lots of algorithm . Read this [web](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/context_features)